# What is the proper format for the flag service calls?

Tags: 7, services, flags

I'm running Drupal 7 with the [Services 3](http://drupal.org/project/services) and the [Flag Service](http://drupal.org/project/flag_service) modules installed. I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to format the the call in REST format.  Can someone provide a short example?

Comment: Actually this pertains to any non CRUD bases REST server request. I can't find documentation on how test the Voting API Service, the Flag Service or the Push Notifications Service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The flag service module (and probably the others you've listed in your comments) define their resources as actions, so you access them at a URL like:

```
http://server/[endpoint]/[module]/[action].json.
```

So for the flag action provided by the flag module that would be something like:

```
http://server/endpoint/flag/flag.json
```

This little snippet works well for me, based on a REST server with no authentication turned on and an endpoint with the path 'api':

```
$url = 'http://server-name/api/flag/flag.json';

$args = array(
  'flag_name' => 'bookmarks',
  'content_id' => 8,
  'action' => 'flag',
  'uid' => 1,

  // You wouldn't normally want this, the flag module provides it as an override 
  // but it's a security risk. With proper authentication you can safely remove it.
  // I'm just using it for testing.
  'skip_permission_check' => 1 
);

// Perform the curl
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($args));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

$http_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($curl);

if ($http_code == 200) {
  // Success
}
```

Answering the original question (*What is the proper format for the flag service calls?*), it's simply a matter of calling the correct URL and POSTing the required arguments to it, from whatever programming language you might be using.

Comment: this totally worked for the flag server, I've had a trouble with the other two, but I attribute that to the module (both being dev versions, thanks